# Declaring and accessing an enum in a singleton class- C++

Tags: c++

C++ Beginner Question!

If there is an enum in the public section of a singleton class, what is the correct way to use the **enum values** from outside the singleton class.

```
class MySingletonClass
{
    public:
      static MySingletonClass & Singleton();

      enum
      {
          eCodeZero         = 0,
          eCodeOne      = 1
      }MsgQueueCodes;
    protected:

          MySingletonClass ();
          ~MySingletonClass ();
};
```

I was able to access the enum values like this from outside this class.

```
MySingletonClass::Singleton().eCodeZero
MySingletonClass::Singleton().eCodeOne
```

My question is,

1. Is this the proper way to do this?
2. Is there any alternate ways exist?
3. What is the syntax for declaring an enum variable in another class? [need to do something like `MySingletonClass::MsgQueueCodes myMsgQCode;` // Not the correct syntax]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Use `MySingletonClass::eCodeZero`, etc.. for access. You published it, so use it =P The decl of the enum is  not part of some instance (though they can have natural access to it); it is part of the *class decl* and thus anyone with proper access to the class can access the enum directly as shown.

Comment: By declaring enum within a class you are trying to limit the scope of the enum within that class. then y are you trying to declare enum in another class??

Comment: Since you're a beginner I'll just say this: don't get in the habit of using singletons.  They're not a great idea, almost ever.

Comment: I second that, @JohnZwinck.  You can run into a huge amount of bother when you use singletons willy-nilly.  In fact, for the last couple of years I've been maintaining a large project that has exactly this problem, and there's very little I can do about it apart from spend the rest of my days treading carefully.

Comment: @paddy : Almost all books on design patterns state "Singleton pattern is the simplest". It will be simple in concept. But IMHO, proper implementation in a multithreaded environment is not trivial. I have seen [not read yet] scores of pages of documentation[by Scott meyers] about how to do this properly.

Answer (score 2):

- If your `enum` only relevant to `MySingletonClass` then is is good to declare it inside the class. then you have to use `MySingletonClass::eCodeZero` in the functions that defining outside the class definition.
- If your same `enum` use in some other classes then best way to declare it outside the class but withing the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

The code is valid, and might be what you intend. Note that `MsgQueueCodes` is declared as an member variable of the (unnamed) enum. Maybe you want:

```
class MySingletonClass
{
    public:
      static MySingletonClass & Singleton();

      enum MsgQueueCodes
      {
          eCodeZero     = 0,
          eCodeOne      = 1
      };
    MsgQueueCodes code;
    protected:

          MySingletonClass ();
          ~MySingletonClass ();
};
```

Then you can write:

```
MySingletonClass::MsgQueueCodes code =  MySingletonClass::Singleton().eCodeZero;
MySingletonClass::MsgQueueCodes code =  MySingletonClass::Singleton().code;
```

Also, since C++ 11, we have `enum class`, which means better scoping for enum names. See for example:
[Strongly typed enumerations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Strongly_typed_enumerations)